# Unable to select the specified database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a model that calls MySQL stored procedure. In order for my procedure to work i had to change "thread_stack" value in my.ini to 256K from 128K default. 
When i execute it first time, everything goes as normal.

But when i refresh view for that model or any other i have in my project, i get "Unable to select the specified database: db_name" error and error repeats until i restart MySQL server. When i restart server, again, first call to model works fine, and refresh or call to any other model pops up an error.

Any idea how to work this out?

Comment: Try running stored procedure from phpmyadmin does it "stuck" itself? I mean, whatever you do (in that procedure) may cause MySQL server to stop. In my opinion this has nothing to do with codeigniter.

Answer (score -2):

if you working on localhost 
then
change into config/database.php

old

```
$db[‘default’][‘username’] = “”;
```

new

```
$db[‘default’][‘username’] = “root
```

”;